# How to avoid implementing empty constructors in derived classes?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have a base class that has a large number of derived classes, and the base class has several constructors. In all my derived classes I have to implement empty constructors to forward the arguments to the base constructors. Is it possible to somehow tell C# to use the derived constructors?

For example, if using this base class.

```
 class BaseTool
 {
      public BaseTool(string Arg1, string Arg2)
      {
          // do stuff.
      }

      public BaseTool(string Arg1)
      {
          // do stuff.
      }

      public BaseTool(int Arg1)
      {
          // do stuff.
      }
  }
```

I would have to implement all the above constructors with those arguments, and then call `: base(...)` to forward them to the derived class. This is resulting in a lot of classes that have empty constructors. Seems like a lot of wasted code.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is making `static` methods instead of instance constructors. So for example `public static T Create<T>(string Arg1, string Arg2) where T : BaseTool, new() { var instance = new T(); /* do stuff, to instance. */ return instance; }`. This could be called as `var newDT = BaseTool.Create<DerivedTool>("foo", "bar");`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: If you post that as an answer I will upvote it :-)

Comment: @dtb I posted as answer.

Answer (score 4):

Constructors are not inherited from base classes, so there is no way around declaring all constructors in each derived class. However, you could automate this repetitive task with, for example, [T4 Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

(Promoted from a comment, by request.)

The only thing I can think of is making static methods instead of instance constructors. So for example:

```
class BaseTool
{
  public static T Create<T>(string Arg1, string Arg2) where T : BaseTool, new()
  {
    var instance = new T();
    // do stuff, to instance (which is a BaseTool)
    return instance;
  }

  public static T Create<T>(string Arg1) where T : BaseTool, new()
  {
    var instance = new T();
    // do stuff, to instance (which is a BaseTool)
    return instance;
  }

  public static T Create<T>(int Arg1) where T : BaseTool, new()
  {
    var instance = new T();
    // do stuff, to instance (which is a BaseTool)
    return instance;
  }
}
```

This could be called as:

```
var newDT = BaseTool.Create<DerivedTool>("foo", "bar");
```

or, from inside some `BaseTool` (since methods *are* inherited, in contrast to constructors), just:

```
var newDT = Create<DerivedTool>("foo", "bar");
```

I know it's a little less elegant than `var newDT = new DerivedTool("foo", "bar");`.